# mySQL: Stored procedures are more secure than queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a website using mySQL database and I want to do common tasks like add users, modify their info, etc. I can do it perfectly with regular queries. Im using prepared statements to increment security. 
Should I use stored procedures to increment the security or the results will be the same? I though that may be using stored procedures I can restrict the direct interaction that a possible attacker could have with the real query. I'm wrong?

Comment: I removed the mysqli tag. The specific API is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would depend on what language youre using. Using a prepared statement with a sql string that contains all of the sql to be executed, or using a prepared statement with a sql string that executes a stored procedure are going to be about equivalent in most languages. The language *should* take care of the security around the prepared statement. C# for example will validate the input, so sql injection vulnerabilities are greatly reduced unless your prepared statement is written so poorly that feeding it bad (but expected, ie, 1 vs 0) variables will dramatically change the result set. Other languages may not provide the same level of validation though, so there may be an advantage depending on exactly what your stored proc looks like.

Using a stored procedure is better for maintainability, but there are not many scenarios where its going to provide any sort of change in security level, assuming the program is properly designed to begin with. The only example i can think of off the top of my head would be a stored procedure that takes raw sql strings from user input, and then executes that sql against the db. This is actually less secure than using a prepared statement unless you went to great lengths to validate the acceptable input, in which case you better have a really good reason for using such a stored proc in the first place.

Basically, what I'm saying boils down to the fact that you're going to need to read the documentation for your language about prepared statements, and determine what vulnerabilities, if any, using prepared statements may have, and whether or not those can be eliminated in your specific scenario by switching to a prepared statement that calls out a stored procedure instead of executing a sql query directly.

Answer (score 0):

The results would be the same (assuming that you set your stored procedure up right).

there appears to be a pretty good write up on it [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  Though I would never suggest you try to escape user input yourself. (They mention this as option 3)